# How come in two's complementary, 1001 and 11111001 are both -7?

Tags: signed, twos-complement

When I learned two's complimentary, I was taught, that for a signed number,

`0111` represents `7`,
so by using two's complementary,

```
0111 -> 1000 + 1 -> 1001, is -7
```

so 1001 represents `-7`.

While I refreshed this concept on YouTube, I see a video that is saying,

`0000 0111` represents `7`, so by using two's complementary,

```
0000 0111 -> 1111 1000 + 1 -> 1111 1001, is -7,
```

thus, `11111001` represents `-7`.

I got confused. So by just looking at a signed binary number, how can we determine its value? I thought `11111001` should equal to `-121`, since the first number MSB is `1`, so it is negative, and `1111001` is `-121` in decimal, so shouldn't `11111001` be `-121`? What did I do wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: "the first number MSB is 1, so it is negative, and 1111001 is [121]" - that would be [Signed magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representation#Signed_magnitude_representation), which is not the same as two's complement.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew this concept before. I guess I have to read more to have a deeper understanding to distinguish these two concepts!

Comment: If you understood this... you understood everything about 2's complement. Im happy someone already helped you!

Comment: @GabrielOshiro sorry for my late reply! Now I understand this. Thanks guys!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two examples is the number of bits you are using for each number.

1001 is -7 with 4 bits and 11111001 is -7 with 8 bits.

If you add up the negative and the positive of the same absolute number the result will be zero.

Both are -7 + 7 = 0

```
1001 + 0111 = 1|0000 

11111001 + 00000111 = 1|00000000
```

Comment: Yea I can say that's valid. So when we speak signed binary numbers, we have to specify the context as how many bits we are talking about? Then how can a computer determine if 11111001 is -7 or it is -121?

Comment: I am not up to speed with the latest hardware. But up to my knowledge both of the things you are asking belong to the architecture of the computer. The number of bits is given by the word size (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) and how it performs math operations is also built into the design of the arithmetic logic unit (ALU).

Comment: I would just note that 1001 is -7 in 4 bits, 11001 is -7 in 5 bits, 111001 is -7 in 6 bits, etc. It doesn't matter how many 1's you put at the front. 11111001 is only -121 in [signed magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representation#Signed_magnitude_representation).

Comment: Got it. Knowing the existence of signed magnitude representation, I understand this more. Thanks guys!