# Question about going from binary to hexadecimal?? and going from hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, bit

**Question on an assignment:**

How to express -20 (in decimal) as fixed point notation, 8 bits, 2's complement.?

**Answer:**

EC(16 ---> in hexadecimal.

**Question:**

I understand how to get that answer. I convert the -20 in base 10 to 2's complement and you get 11101100. 1110=E in hexadecimal and 1100=C in hexadecimal.

What is confusing me, however, is that EC(16 is equal to 236 in decimal. How can EC(16 equal both -20 and 236 in decimal??!

I am confused as to how that works?

Comment: It just depends on how the bits are interpreted. One is a signed value and the other is unsigned. Some programing languages let you make the distinction at the time of defining the variable.

Comment: So if I was to convert the EC(16 back to decimal (signed), I would get the -20 again? Can you explain how I could obtain the value of -20 from EC?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394643/how-come-in-twos-complementary-1001-and-11111001-are-both-7/52394713#52394713

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Juan wrote: *It just depends on how the bits are interpreted.* More specifically, in your case it depends only on how the most significant bit is interpreted. The lower seven bits in both cases add up to 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> = 4 + 8 + 32 + 64 = 108. Now, the highest bit if used as an ordinary value bit has the value 2<sup>7</sup> = 128 and thus makes 108 + 128 = 236, while if used as the sign bit it has the value −2<sup>7</sup> = −128 and thus makes 108 − 128 = −20.